# Google Drive API - Problem with Service Account Storage

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

I try hard to find the answer from other topics but nothing.

My project let user to create request transaction and system generate PDF file and auto upload that file to Drive by Service Account.

I use Service Account by personal account (@gmail.com) to use Drive API and work perfectly, the question is :

1. Service Account Storage limit to 15GB and how to increase this storage (Other topic say noway for personal account)
2. How to transfer ownership from service account to personal account without request anymore because the project auto upload file to Drive (Other topic say impossible)
3. Both 1 and 2 can be posible if I use Google Workspace with domain ?
4. How much storage for Service Account on Workspace Account ?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Please take note that each post must be focused on one question  only cause this can be tagged as 'Needs more focus'.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.